# How to launch the apk when there is change in phone state (broadcast receiver) that will start the service

Tags: java, android

I want to create without ui application I want to start my application on change in phone state and that will start another service that will do the task 
 code but is not working

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle == null)
        return;
    String phoneNumber = null;
    // Incoming call
    String state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
    if ((state != null)
               && (state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)))
    {
        phoneNumber = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER); 

        Intent i = new Intent(context,ServiceFromBr.class);
        context.startService(i);
    }
    // Outgoing call
    else if (state == null) {       
        phoneNumber = bundle.getString(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        Intent i = new Intent(context,ServiceFromBr.class);
        context.startService(i);
    }
}
```

and service code is:

```
public class ServiceFromBr extends Service 
{
    public void onCreate()
    {
        Toast t= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in Service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        t.show();
    }
}


<service android:name=".ServiceFromBr"></service>
  <receiver android:name=".BroadcastStart"
                  android:enabled="true"
                  android:exported="true">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />

      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: what is not working? Is the service not starting or the broadcast receiver is catching the broadcast ?

Comment: broadcast  receiver is not catching nor starting the service

Answer (score 0):

it is used in broadcast receiver rather than service.

launch other app from yours :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName,mainActivity));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

You can get the main activity like this:

```
Intent mIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName); 
if (mIntent != null) {
   if (mIntent.getComponent() != null) {
mainActivity = mIntent.getComponent().getClassName();
  }
}
```

and you have to add main activity in manifest file.

your code looks like following one....

```
String mainActivity;
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")) {
        String state = intent.getExtras().getString(
                TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

        if ((state != null)
                && (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))) {
            CallLogReceiver.phoneNo = intent.getExtras().getString(
                    "incoming_number");

            Intent mIntent = context.getPackageManager()
                    .getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.calculator"); //here i take example of calculator demo
            if (mIntent != null) {
                if (mIntent.getComponent() != null) {
                    mainActivity = mIntent.getComponent().getClassName();
                }
            }
            Intent launchIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            launchIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            launchIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
                    "com.example.calculator", mainActivity));
            launchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(launchIntent);
                            //further logic of your code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion..... but i want to start my application without activity and launch my app with the call trigger

Comment: then what you want to launch from broadcast receiver...??

Comment: i want to lunch my application as broadcast receiver tigger

Comment: then your application main activity and package name will be placed in above code.

Comment: thanks for the help... what should i do in broadcast receiver class then